# scroll parent page to top iframe submit in Firefox

Tags: iframe, scroll, google-apps-script

Anyone know how to get a page that has an embedded iframe form to scroll back to the top of the page when the iframe form is submitted? e.g. I have an embedded Google form on a page. When I submit the form, I need the page to scroll back to the top so that the confirmation message is viewable. Adding `onload="scroll(0,0)` to the iframe works well for Chrome, not so much for Firefox (version 54 something). Or if anyone knows of a feature in Google Forms or google app scripts that will accomplish the same thing, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: You could just hide the rest of the form with display:none.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)
```

This works.

Comment: <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="http://www.prontopage.net/member/signup.php" onsubmit="parent.scrollTo(0,0); return showValues(this);">